# Missing edit option on some Attachments

Tags: attachment, files

From some of my attachments edit option is not visible for me. Why would that be?

[image: Attachments]

Comment: That may be **File**, shared to the record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because those files are uploaded via Chatter or Library. Files uploaded through these do not have option to edit.

Same behavior is shown in classic also. Below screen:-
[image]

This may be confusing because it is not showing Attachment type. Classic UI shows the `Type`.